# What is wrong with setting up my resource bundle?

Tags: java, jsf, localization

I'm setting up just a basic resource bundle like this:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <message-bundle>src.main.resources.messages</message-bundle>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>src.main.resources.text</base-name>
        <var>text</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

usage:

```
    <h1>#{text.header}</h1>
```

result:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find bundle for base name src.main.resources.text, locale en

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name src.main.resources.text, locale en
```

`text.properties` looks like this:

```
header=Welcome!
```

What is wrong with this?
What is strange: eclipse can resolve the text property. Even give me code completion hints for other text properties defined.
ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a fully qualified class/properties file name in `<base-name>`.

In your `<base-name>src.main.resources.text</base-name>` the `src.main.resources` seems to be a part of Maven folder structure where your `text.properties` file is located. It is in `src/main/resources` isn't it?

You don't need to specify folders in `<base-name>`, try just `text`:

```
<base-name>text</base-name>
```

Comment: Do you mean `<base-name>text</base-name>` ?